# on button click subtract 1 from my database table column quantity asp.net vb sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net web form and when a button event is clicked i would like to have  one of my database table columns called quantity subtract from its already stored integer number.

I am aware some sort of SQL statement will be needed to minus the quantity column by 1 but am unsure of how to achieve this.

any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Read about ADO.NET. There are thousands of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure as an update query.

```
USE [MyDB]

GO
Create Procedure [dbo].[myproc]
( 
@SomeID bigint,
)
as
set nocount on
update MyTable set 
MyField=SomeMath-SomeMath,
where SomeID=@SomeID
```

Then need to link it on the web page (aspx.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class _MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 SqlConnection con;
 //Here we declare the parameter which we have to use in our application
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 SqlParameter Id = new SqlParameter();

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    con = new SqlConnection("server=(local); database=mydb;uid=myuser;pwd=Mypass");
    cmd = new SqlCommand("myproc", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = MyValue;

 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
 Response.Redirect("ThanksPage.aspx");
}
}
```